# Как написать тест под такой реактивный подход?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Есть кусок кода

```
getCompositeDisposable().add(getInteractor()
                .sendMail(email,String.valueOf(isSignedAgreement))
                .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<AuthorizationModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(AuthorizationModel authorizationModel) {
                        getMvpView().hideLoading();
                        if (authorizationModel.getOperationResult().equals(ServerCodeUtils.RESPONSE_SUCCESS)){
                            getInteractor().saveEmail(email);
                            getMvpView().showMessage(R.string.code_sent_to_email);
                            getMvpView().toVerificationFragment();
                        }else{
                            getMvpView().onError(authorizationModel.getServerErrorModel().getErrorMessage());
                            getInteractor().errorRecievedMetrics();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        getMvpView().hideLoading();
                        getMvpView().showMessage(R.string.http_error);
                        getInteractor().errorRecievedMetrics();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                }));
```

как его покрыть тестами ???

Comment: Может тут что-то полезное будет: https://medium.com/@vanniktech/testing-rxjava-code-made-easy-4cc32450fc9a